# ¿Arrancando con Asincronismo en JS... como puedo pintar lo que traigo por consola en pantalla?

Tags: javascript, fetch, asincronismo

Tengo este code:

```
fetch(API_URL)
.then(function(response){
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(user){
    
    
    const article = document.querySelector('.card-description');
    
    console.log(typeof user)

    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        console.log('user', user.results[i].name);
        console.log('img', user.results[i].image);
   
    }


})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('Algo fallo', error)
})
```

Básicamente me estoy trayendo nombre y una img de un personaje de una API publica, la cuestión es que quiero reflejar esos resultados en un div... yo cree un template literal, pero no me pinta nada... ósea estoy medio confundido, si alguien tiene un manual o algo como guia se los agradeceré

Comment: ¿Podría ampliar el ejemplo con lo que ha intentado hasta el momento por favor? Es decir, agregar el ejemplo con la API_URL para poder replicarlo y el código que está utilizando para "reflejar los resultados en un div"

Answer (score 1):

Tu código lo puedes optimizar utilizando una función asyncrona:

```javascript
    const consumirAPI = async (API_URL, callback) => {
       try {
    
         const response = await fetch(API_URL);
         const user = await response.json();
    
         if(callback) callback(user);
    
       } catch({message}) { console.error(message); }
    };
```

Y lo podrías utilizar para consumir cualquier petición y el proceso que quieras realizar lo puedes enviar en un callback, si .results es un arreglo sería más fácil que utilices un forEach:

```javascript
    consumirAPI((user) => {
      if(typeof user !== "object") throw new Error("Sin resultados");
      let {results} = user;
      if(!Array.isArray(results) || results.length === 0) throw new Error("Sin resultados");
      // si lo quieres hacer con un template string
      const article = document.querySelector('.card-description');
      let template = "";
      results.map(({name, image}) => {
         template += `
              // etiquetas
              <img src=${image} />
              <span>${name}</span>
         `;
      });
      article.innerHTML = template;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un elemento html de imagen e inyectarlo en el html.
Ej:

```
const img = document.createElement("img")
img.src = myimg
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

Lo mismo sería para mostrar datos en texto.
Pd: no necesariamente tienes que inyectar los elementos al body, puedes hacerlo dentro de un div.